# c++ clock_gettime() and daylight savings

Tags: c++, time, clock, dst

I am using clock_gettime() in my C++ program to get the current time.  However, the return value is seconds since epoch in UTC. This code can get messed up in my time zone during daylight savings when the time shifts by one hour.

The system itself has NTP syncing it to always give the correct time in EST. Is there a way to get clock_gettime() to report the local time instead of UTC so I can avoid the daylight savings issue?

Comment: Why don't you just convert from UTC to local time? Separate "getting the time" from "converting to local time".

Comment: Sure, but then I have to change the conversion factor twice a year manually in my code.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting hard-coding it. I was suggesting using a date/time library which was time zone aware to perform the conversion.

Comment: Also consider using the [cctz](https://github.com/google/cctz) library to do the conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realize that `time` also reports seconds since the beginning of 1970 (in a `time_t`). If you take the `tv_sec` member of the `timespec` and pass it to `localtime` or `localtime_r`, you should get what you want.

```
timespec tsv;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tsv);
time_t t = tsv.tv_sec; // just in case types aren't the same
tm tmv;
localtime_r(&t, &tmv); // populate tmv with local time info
```

And you can deal with the `tv_nsec` member of the `timespec` however you wish.

Comment: This code doesn't seem to compile for me, I run into this: error: cannot convert ?timespec*? to ?const time_t*? for argument ?1? to ?tm* localtime_r(const time_t*, tm*)?

Comment: @user788171: Code compiles for me verbatim. I pasted it in from compiled code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows, you can use this [GetTimeZoneInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724421%28VS.85%29.aspx), but you have to include the Windows API.

Another methode to achieve this would be the struct tm. You will find the details here: [struct tm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/). "The Daylight Saving Time flag (tm_isdst) is greater than zero if Daylight Saving Time is in effect, zero if Daylight Saving Time is not in effect, and less than zero if the information is not available." I think this is the easier way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use Boost, you can control all of this explicitly by using the date time libraries: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/date_time.html

I've had to deal with time on a variety of platforms and in a variety of languages, and I find the boost libraries wildly superior to anything else available.

Comment: I'm sorry, this just isn't very useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <time.h>
time_t rawtime;
struct tm *timeinfo;

    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
    if (timeinfo->tm_isdst)
        Hour -= 1; // daylight savings time
```

Comment: This code is what I used in Windows Visual Studio C++

Comment: The above code is from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/

Comment: But if you only use date and time from timeinfo, the month is WRONG.